# Missing authorization headers with Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers, authorization

I want Apache to pass by default authorization headers to PHP. So I am using Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) with mod_php that allows "Apache authentication headers to be passed through by default".

Here are the apache modules install.

core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_headers mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php7 mod_proxy mod_proxy_ajp mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_connect mod_proxy_html mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_wstunnel mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_slotmem_shm mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status mod_xml2enc

Here is my virtualHost configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName piwal-elgg.com
                DocumentRoot /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/WEB/piwal

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /xxx/xxx/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile   /xxx/xxx/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

                <Directory /xxx/xxx/xxx/WEB/piwal>
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have read a lot of documents on this topic and some of them ask me to add additional rules in the .htaccess file.

Some of those roles are the following.

1- .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

2- .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

3- .htaccess or apache virtual host

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

4- .htaccess or apache virtual host

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

5- .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

None of the above settings are working. "Apache authentication headers are not passed through by default".

But when I add RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" to my virtualHost configuration. In this case, the header is processed correctly by the server.

Could someone help me with this issue ?

Here is the output of my $_SERVER supergloble array

```
Array
(
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL] => /webdav/virtual/
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI] => https://xxxx-xxxx.com/webdav/virtual/
    [REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => 
    [REDIRECT_HTTPS] => on
    [REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI] => xxxx-xxxx.com
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SCRIPT_URL] => /webdav/virtual/
    [SCRIPT_URI] => https://xxxx-xxxx.com/webdav/virtual/
    [HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => 
    [HTTPS] => on
    [SSL_TLS_SNI] => xxxx-xxxx.com
    [HTTP_HOST] => xxxx-xxxx.com
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => Elgg=or2a18jbqubrnkqk38mhhvguc5
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxx-xxxx.com Port 443
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
    [SERVER_NAME] => xxxx-xxxx.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.1.1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/WEB/xxx-3-3-1
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/WEB/xxx-3-3-1
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/WEB/xxx-3-3-1/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 41500
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /webdav/virtual/
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /webdav/virtual/
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1616958400.0139
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1616958400
    [PHP_AUTH_USER] => 
    [PHP_AUTH_PW] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [`CGIPassAuth On`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#cgipassauth) (Apache 2.4.13+) in either the `<Directory>` container (inside your vHost) or in `.htaccess`.

> `CGIPassAuth` allows scripts access to HTTP authorization headers such as Authorization, which is required for scripts that implement HTTP Basic authentication. Normally these HTTP headers are hidden from scripts. This is to disallow scripts from seeing user ids and passwords used to access the server when HTTP Basic authentication is enabled in the web server. This directive should be used when scripts are allowed to implement HTTP Basic authentication.

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#cgipassauth

---

Note that if you are setting an environment variable `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` in `.htaccess` then you may need to check for `REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` (note the `REDIRECT_` prefix) in your PHP script if mod_rewrite is being used to rewrite the request, since any env vars that are set on the first pass are renamed in subsequent passes: `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` etc. etc.

---

*Aside:* All 5 methods you've used to explicitly set the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` env var are really "the same" - you would not expect one method to work and another not. The only slight exception to that is #4. With the `SetEnvIf`, it is more reliable to explicitly capture the group and use the `$1` backreference (as you are doing in #3) instead of using the `$0` backreference that "should" contain the full match. In some cases, the `$0` backreference is not set when the regex argument does not "look like"<sup>1</sup> a regex (although I would not expect that to be an issue here).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>By "look like", I mean where the regex contains no special meta characters and contains only latin characters, eg. `helloworld` - which "looks like" an ordinary string. In cases like this Apache/`SetEnvIf` appears to do a simple substring comparison and no regex backreferences are captured.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrWhite. I did it, I added CGIPassAuth On in the <Directory> container of my virtualHost. But I still have the same behavior.

Here is how I am testing.

`$headers = array_change_key_case(apache_request_headers());
if(empty($headers['authorization'])){
      echo "authorization not set";
}`


But when I add RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" to my virtualHost configuration. The header is processed correctly by the server.

Regards,

Comment: Check the PHP `$_SERVER` superglobal array.

Comment: (You should add that information to your question, rather than posting - unformatted - across multiple comments.) That header does indeed seem to be missing (or not set). Have you confirmed that the `Authorization` header is being sent in the HTTP request from the client? How have you implemented the HTTP authentication?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the information to my question.

I really don't know why apache is not sending `Authorization` header.
I am implementing a webdav server using sabredav framework for PHP. it required apache to send `Authorization` header. Whatever I did `Authorization` header is not send. only when I set it manually in virtualhost config.