# Authorization header missing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I create a website running on a subdirectory and in health status WordPress shows that "Authorization header is missing".

My `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress`
# are created automatically and can only be changed through WordPress filters.
# Manual changes between these markers will be overwritten.<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]

Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
Header set Permissions-Policy "accelerometer=Origin(), autoplay=(), camera=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), payment=(), publickey-credentials-get=(), usb=()"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Expect-CT: max-age=2592000

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I flush permalinks, but without any changes!

How to solve this problem?

Comment: _Aside:_ I assume `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` is not included as part of the comment in your actual code?

Comment: The `Authorization` header may well not be set as far as WP is concerned if you using PHP as CGI (as opposed to an Apache module), but the first `RewriteRule` is an attempt to workaround this issue. What version of Apache are you using? Have you tried setting  `CGIPassAuth On`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66824195/missing-authorization-headers-with-apache AND