# HTTP Authentication + PHP + Apache Server API CGI/FastCGI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cgi, http-authentication

I have a system implemented in php that has been working for years and uses head HTTP_AUTHORIZATION for logging.

Now the hosting provider made changes to the server and the server does not receive the header.

Searching here for information I find that it has to do with the new server api on the server: CGI/FastCGI.

I have the following htaccess that worked before the change (and now it doesn't have the header):

```
RewriteBase /
    Options FollowSymLinks
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
        RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
        
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

And making these changes according to recommendations does not work either:

```
RewriteBase /
    Options FollowSymLinks
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
        
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
        RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
        
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

I also tried this alternative:

```
RewriteBase /

Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    CGIPassAuth On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Some more details:

PHP Version 5.5.38

Server API CGI/FastCGI

Any ideas what to change to fix them?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `CGIPassAuth on` as suggested in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66825530/369434)? "making these changes" - you certainly should not be simply adding that `SetEnvIf` directive before the existing rules (that will do nothing) - that is intended to be instead of the first mod_rewrite rule. Remove the first mod_rewrite rule.

Comment: @MrWhite If I tried with CGIPassAuth on as indicated in that answer. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Does it go inside the IfModule mod_rewrite.c tag?

Comment: Update the question by adding how I use it @MrWhite

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the `CGIPassAuth` directive. You don't need the `<IfModule>` wrappers and you don't need the last section (that uses `ErrorDocument`). mod_rewrite must be enabled otherwise you would be getting a 500 error (since you've put the `RewriteBase` directive in the "wrong place".) (Although that `RewriteBase` directive is not required either if these are all the directives you have?) Do you see the `Authorization` header as part of the HTTP request sent from the browser? With `SetEnvIf` in place, add the contents of the PHP `$_SERVER` superglobal to you question.